# Non-biased User Interface for building training set

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I want to use machine learning to detect objects of type A among objects of types B-Z.  I require human expertise to initially classify these objects as A, B, C... Z.  The individuals who can provide the initial classification are not familiar at all with machine learning and need a simple interface.

Unfortunately, type A objects are naturally rare (< 1%) in the population.  In most datasets type A objects do not occur at all, in a few datasets they will be present at ~5%.  Generating a balanced training set will require somehow informing the user as they go along if they are lacking objects of a particular type relative to another.  However, depending on the random order of presentation of the datasets, type A objects may not occur until well after the beginning of classification.

The challenge I am facing is to create a user interface that will encourage users to classify approximately the same number of objects of each type, without orienting the user.  I have to find a way to push the user to classify all the type A objects they find, but not invent type A objects where there are none.

Do you know of any publications that address these challenges?  Or examples of similar interfaces to gain inspiration?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is more a UX question I suppose where what you are trying to avoid is an enforced hierarchy. Visual hierarchies encourage action in some direction (colour, positioning etc) and are hard to avoid.

Examples: http://www.creativebloq.com/ux/ways-guide-website-visitors-111413511

If there is a full alphabets worth of object types, creating a non-list based UI will be key. Rule out thing like dropdowns because people are more oriented towards the top and bottom of those lists. A horizontal, always visible button layout would be safer (though people would tend toward the edges and centre naturally, just be aware).

Avoid scroll at all costs, it slows everything down and people just want to do what is easiest, which in this case means select the same thing over and over.

If you want an even distribution of answers then actively guide people. Give feedback (a simple counter for each class would work) and tell people they should be roughly even. This may be difficult to do well without seriously increasing the user's congnitive load. Keeping track of 20+ numbers is difficult.

Also be mindful of how complex the object being classified is and give it the prominent positioning in the UI.

White space is your friend to allow people to quickly classify (don't spend as much time hunting for the button their trying to hit) and minimise the human time spent. If it work very quickly, give it 2 human passes and cross validate their classifications, though this may only be relevant if the classification process is highly subjective.

Also consider linespace for speed of use. 
http://uxmovement.com/content/how-margins-and-line-lengths-affect-user-reading/